# Macbook Pro is connected to wifi, but can't connect to internet?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I've recently changed my router(+NAS), Time Capsule, due to [this problem](https://9to5mac.com/2021/07/08/apple-time-capsule-failure-hard-drive/), and now using
new router, which is [this one](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/MR2200ac).

It's working very good with my iPhone, iPad, two iMac and a Mac Mini. However, when it comes to my Macbook Pro, they don't work as intended.

Before changing my router the wi-fi internet connection was very fine. So, I thought the router is having some problem, but it doesn't make sense since every other device I have is working very nicely. Then, I re-connected my Time Capsule to see if I can connect to internet with my MBP, and it works. So, I have no idea what's happening right now.

The problem is only happening with the new router, other wifi is working fine, like workplace wifi, tethering, etc...

I've checked if I'm having any error code or something but there wasn't anything I can find of. Now I don't know what to do.

---

**Edit:**
So far, I've tried the solution recommended by comment below:

- Rebooting/Resetting router. Nothing changes.
- Resetting DNS settings. Nothing changes.
- [Deleting network related plists](https://macreports.com/how-to-reset-network-settings-on-mac/)(Method 2)+Reboot MBP. Nothing changes.
- Check if the problem is still occur in Safe mode. It does.
- Check if the problem is caused by 2.4/5Ghz bandwidth. No, it wasn't.
- Unplugged all USB devices. Still, there's problem.
- Changed MTU to 1492. Nothing changes.
- Tried creating new network locations. Nothing changes.

I'm only using DHCP because I use this mac when I'm not in home, such as workplace, so using a static IP address is not a very smart idea.

I am now talking with Apple to investigate what's causing the issue.

Comment: You can verify wifi preferences with this link. DNS and Proxy can be at the origin of problem s : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-wi-fi-preferences-on-mac-mh11935/11.0/mac/11.0

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that in my post, my DNS is 8.8.8.8 - 1.1.1.1 - 8.8.4.4 - 1.0.0.1, so I highly doubt it could be an issue. But I tried to set it default anyway, there was no change though. I sometimes use VPN but I have never used proxy. Anyway, I kind of went extreme on this: Deleted network plists, reset NVRAM, SMC, sadly no changes(again).

Comment: Which version of MacOS are you running on your Macbook? Try deactivating private address and/or set the MTU size to 1456.

Comment: @Skye-AT If you have a VPN, you can try thirst uninstalle it. Then you can compare advanced values with the sames on functional Mac.

Comment: @slartibartfast Mines on Big sur 11.5.2. By private address, do you mean fixed/static IP address? If so, I'm only using DHCP. How do you change MTU on mac?

Comment: @Jean_JD It's not application or like that, it's just L2TP settings which connects to my home router RV340. So, if I don't activate it, it doesn't do nothing(as far as I aware).

Comment: my mistake, MacOS does not randomize the MAC address. Which IP get your Macbook assigned when connected to the network? Is the problem related to WLAN only (does it work if connected by cable)? Do you have any USB device connected (try to disconnect them all to check for interference)? Try to create a new network location (via system preferences).

Comment: If you boot the Mac in Safe mode (push shift key at boot), have you the same problem?

Comment: [This page summarizes what you can try](https://osxdaily.com/2020/11/23/how-fix-macos-big-sur-wifi-issues/)

Comment: @slartibartfast 1: 10.10.10.x if you mean private IP address. 2: Yes, it works fine with cable.

Comment: @Jean_JD Tested it: I do have a problem on safe mode too.

Comment: The last thing I see is, maybe, a problem between 2,4 and 5 ghz wifi features. If you can define on the router two  different wifi entries  you can test if you have the same problem with 2,4 and 5 ghz.

Comment: I purposely disabled 5Ghz(because my house has too many obstacle that made of metals) but I enabled 5Ghz and tried to connect it - no changes. I think it's time to ask to Apple...

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the problem and the steps you've tried so far directly in the text? Things tend to get lost in the comments.

Comment: @nohillside I've updated my post.

Comment: Did you reboot your router as well?

Comment: @nohillside Of course I have. Plus, I've reset it like 3 or 4 times. Yeah, I'll put that in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a while of talking with Apple CS, we found out that the problem was on the router side...

For the reasons unknown, the router wasn't allowing my MBP to connect it. I've reset the router 3 times(again), but my MBP still didn't connect but other device can(as I wrote earlier). So, I asked for replacement of the router... and voila! it's now working.

I've wasted so many times on this, but yeah, it works now.